# Windows Authentication for OData service returns "401 - Unauthorized" in C# app, but works in browser

Tags: c#, http, wcf-data-services, windows-authentication, ntlm

I am trying to add functionality to my C# app, to test a connection to an OData service which is secured with only Windows Authentication. The following block of code is what I am using to perform this test:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(SERVICE_NAME));
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

myCache.Add(new Uri(SERVICE_NAME), "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential(user, password));
resolver.Credentials = myCache;

//  Do a simple request
request.Credentials = myCache;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
object response = request.GetResponse();  // This is where the exception is thrown
```

When I run the above code, I receive the 401 - Unauthorized error as previously stated. However, when I have Fiddler2 running, the code works fine. So I am using Wireshark instead. In addition, the service works perfect within my browser (Chrome), and if I use Wireshark to compare the HTTP requests/responses for the Authentication, I see that they are nearly identical, except that in Chrome I have: Accept, User-Agent, Accept-Encoding, and Accept-Language headers, while my C# app does not have these. The only other difference is that my C# app sets the "Negotiate Seal" flag in the NTLM header, while Chrome does not set this flag.

Despite these differences, the authentication phase seems to work fine in the C# app, up until the service returns a 302 - Redirection, at which point the app tries a GET on the newly redirected URI, which returns a 401 again (when Chrome does the analogous GET, it receives HTTP 200 - OK, and proceeds on its merry way).

So, any ideas what could cause this? Problem with the service? or my code?

Thanks a lot!
-Erik

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two whole days of research and I found the answer. Line 3 in the code above was using the full URI of the service (".../Northwind/Northwind.svc"), when the request was redirected, the credentials no longer applied to the new URI. The solution was to pass in only the beginning part ("...") of the URI. Stupid mistake on my part.